# 403 Forbidden when downloading files (Download quota exceeded for this file, so you can't download it at this time)

Tags: google-drive-api

We're trying to download all the files from a Drive account. The issue can be reproduced with the following code:

```
import requests

f = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/%s' % file_id, params={'access_token': access_token})
download_url = f.json()['downloadUrl']
r = requests.get(download_url, params={'access_token': access_token}, stream=True)
with open('/path/to/file', 'wb') as f:
  for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
    if chunk:
      f.write(chunk)
      f.flush()
```

The third line returns 403 Forbidden.

Here are the interesting points:

- This only seems to happen to large files, with sizes in the range of GBs. The smallest file that is affected is 6 GB, with most of the files having a size of 100 GB.
- We used the download URL of the file resource returned by the Drive API, but it also happens with the download URL of the revision resource.
- When retrying after a few days, some of the affected files were downloaded successfully, but others still had the same error.

*edit:* Trying to download the file manually shows the error "Download quota exceeded for this file, so you can't download it at this time". Searching for this in Google doesn't show any helpful results, so I still don't know how to proceed.

Comment: check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors. You may have to implement exponential back off. Even downloading a file consumes quota as to get download URL, you have to send get request for files.get or the files.list methods.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but we already implement exponential back off. And the error returned for rate limit exceeded is different from what we receive. In the code above there is no content returned but for rate limit exceeded it is mentioned in the content returned.

Comment: @user1591276 im getting the same error, were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while downloading file manually.
Did not try using script.
But can you verify what I followed in case of manual download, and then try the smae using script.

There are two scenario where you can get this error that says “Too many users have Viewed and Downloaded this file recently …..” -

1. In case you have shared Folder and you are not able to download a file with
   the same error -

   Right click-> make a copy of that file and then Download that copy (Right
   Click-> Download)
2. In case you have a shared link and you get this error “Too many users have
   viewed and Downloaded this file recently…”

   Check the url which should look something like this
   `https://drive.google.com/u/7/uc?id=<someID>&​​​export=download`

   Replace **uc** with **open**

   Remove `export=download`

   Link should look something like this
   `https://drive.google.com/u/7/open?id=<someID>&` ​​​​hit Enter and Download the
   file.